# Problem in SQLite selecting an element from a column when not using id

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine, select, random

I have an sqlite database in Unity which I'm trying to select a value from a column that is not id, just like this:

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT Question FROM Questions WHERE Category= 'Art'";
```

But I receive this error in the console *"InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type"*. And I don't know why it occurs.

PS: This is the code:

```
using (IDbConnection dbconn = new SqliteConnection(conn))
    {
        dbconn.Open();

        using (IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand())
        {
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT Question FROM Questions WHERE Category = 'Art'";
            dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

            using (IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    string category = reader.GetString(1);
                    string question = reader.GetString(2);
                    string A = reader.GetString(3);
                    string B = reader.GetString(4);
                    string C = reader.GetString(5);
                    string D = reader.GetString(6);



                }

                reader.Close();

                dbcmd.Dispose();

                dbconn.Close();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your code that executes this query and does stuff with the resulting rows? You know, where the error is thrown?

Comment: I edited the main post. This is the report I receive: InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.VerifyType (Int32 i, DbType typ)
Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.GetInt32 (Int32 i)
Database.InsertQuestion () (at Assets/Scripts/Database.cs:34)
Database.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Database.cs:16)

Comment: cs.34 is "int id = reader.GetInt32(0);". The SELECT search in id by default and doesn't let search in other columns?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get 7 different columns from a query that only includes 1 column in its results, and that one isn't an integer like your code thinks it is.... Your query and your code need to agree on what the data being returned is.